# Changing an AWS RDS MySQL instance to Postgres

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

What is the best way to go about this? I have a mobile app a project team developed whereby they setup the database as a MySQL instance. However, with this new project I have with my own developers, we believe Postgres would better suit or needs - but I want everything on one DB instance (data between the mobile app and the new project will be shared). What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a new RDS instance to switch the engine type to Postgres.

Whilst transitioning you will need to have both running, to migrate the DB across you will want to keep the data synchronised between both. Luckily AWS has the [database migration service](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/).

You should try to migrate your existing application to use this first, then remove the DMS setup and shutdown the MySQL database.